# Recommended title boost?

Tags: lucene, solr

I have a relatively simple Lucene index, being served by Solr.  The index consists of two major fields, title and body, and a few less-important fields.

Most search engines give more relevance to results with matches in the title, over the body.  I'm going to start providing an index-time boost to the title field.

My question is, what values do people typically use for their title fields? 2? 4? 10? 100?

Comment: Why use index time boost instead of search time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you divide the median body length by the median title length. This roughly gives you a factor M - for M appearances of a word in the body, it will appear once in the title.
Now, use something like M*3. This is, of course, a rationalized heuristic, and it is best you iterate over the values. See [Grant Ingersoll's "Debugging Relevance Issues in Search"](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Debugging-Relevance-Issues-Search) for a much more structured discussion.